# Two select boxes with 'Other' options

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have a work code for one select field with other option, that displays a text box when other is selected.  However, I'm having trouble writing the code for 2 select boxes on the same page.

Here is my script.

```js
    function toggleField(val) {
      var o = document.getElementById('other');
      (val == 'Other') ? o.style.display = 'block': o.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

```html
<SELECT NAME="i_skate" SIZE="1" ONCHANGE="toggleField(this.value);">
  <OPTION VALUE="Just a Fan">Just a Fan</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="Everyday">Everyday</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="Few times a Week">Few times a Week Week
  </OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="Few times a Month">Few times a Month Month
  </OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="Other">Other</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="other" ID="other" STYLE="display: none;" SIZE="20">
</TD>
<TD WIDTH="10" ALIGN="LEFT"></TD>
<TD WIDTH="110" ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP">

  <SELECT NAME="my-style" SIZE="1" ONCHANGE="toggleField(this.value);">
    <OPTION VALUE="Street Skate">Street Skate</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="Downhill">Downhill</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="Freestyle">Freestyle</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="Pools-Bowls">Pools-Bowls</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="Vert Halfpipe">Vert Halfpipe</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="Park">Park</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="Mini Ramp">Mini Ramp</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="Other1">Other1</OPTION>
  </SELECT>
  <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="other1" ID="other1" STYLE="display: none;" SIZE="20">
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this the effect you want? http://jsfiddle.net/3b4z9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to just have your second SELECT  tag display the second INPUT box when "Other1" is selected, just like the first one does for "Other".

You are really close, but your Javascript needs some adjusting.  You are currently testing for the changed element of "Other", and then altering the display for the object o which is a reference to the element with id of "other".  You will need to expand on this logic to include your new select box (with option of "Other1") and the corresponding INPUT box.

So, you might need to do something like...

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
function toggleField(val) {
  var o = document.getElementById('other');
  var o1 = document.getElementById('other1');
  (val == 'Other')? o.style.display = 'block' : o.style.display = 'none';
  (val == 'Other1')? o1.style.display = 'block' : o1.style.display = 'none';
}
</SCRIPT>
```

That will expand the same functionality from the first SELECT to the second.

Comment: That is exactly what I was missingvar o1 = document.getElementById('other1');

Comment: You have to mark it as the selected answer.

BTW, depending on what you are hoping the Javascript will do, you might want to change your tests (val == ...).  As it is, only one of the two text boxes will show.  You might want to get a reference to the SELECT and use options[].selected value.  Just let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  Because I'm using (val == ...) as the selector, any user input into the other text fields, simply show up as Other or Other1.  Their input doesn't change the value.  If you have any suggestions there, it would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
function toggleField(val) {
var o = document.getElementById('other');
var o1 = document.getElementById('other1');
var opt = document.getElementById('i_skate');
var opt1 = document.getElementById('my-style');
(opt.options[opt.length-1].selected)? o.style.display = 'block' : o.style.display = 'none';
(opt1.options[opt1.length-1].selected)? o1.style.display = 'block' : o1.style.display = 'none';
}
</SCRIPT>

Comment: Regarding your question of giving credit, there should be a check mark to the left of my answer that you can click to mark it as the "Accepted" answer.

Comment: You have the right coding, I just can't seem to get the users' input into the "Other" field.  A simple text file database.  The form seems to be treating it as something other than a selected option.  It's been a long day and wriiten a ton of scripting today,  maybe I can see the problem after a break.

Comment: All it took was a break.  If anyone else needs to use this code, remember to leave the value blank and rename the the new text input field to the select form name.  Thanks Seth!

Comment: The script is working fine in IE, but not in Chrome or Firefox.  Is it because of the style.display = 'none'? I tried style.visibility = 'hidden'.  That doesn't work either.  Any suggestions?